# Select distinct query across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, distinct

I have an User model with name, surname, email, former_surnames. There is also AdditionalEmail model where I store additional emails for users. Each user can have multiple additional emails. There are relations hasMany and belongsToMany set in each model respectively. 
I have to search across surname, former_surnames, email and addional emails. I tried to use containable behavior and created the following table for query:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'alias' => 'User',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array('User.id = AdditionalEmail.user_id')
    ));
$options['conditions'] = array('OR' => array(
    'User.surname LIKE' => $search,
    'User.former_surnames LIKE' => $search,
    'User.email LIKE' => $search,
    'AdditionalEmail.email LIKE' => $search));
$options['recursive'] = -1;
$options['fields'] = 'DISTINCT User.username, User.name, User.surname, User.former_surnames';
$options['order'] = array('User.surname' => 'asc');
```

The above, however did not work for me. I finally ended up with the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users LEFT JOIN additional_emails ON ( users.id = additional_emails.user_id ) WHERE ((additional_emails.email LIKE  \''. $search .'\') OR (users.email LIKE \''. $search .'\') OR (users.surname LIKE \''. $search .'\') OR (users.former_surnames LIKE \''. $search .'\')) ORDER BY users.surname
```

which works OK. How to build this query using cakephp options for find (or paginate).
Regards
Piotr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $this->User->find('all', 
     array(
         'fields' => array('DISTINCT *'), 
         'joins' => array(
               array(
                    'table' => 'additional_emails',
                    'alias' => 'Email',
                    'type' => 'left',
                    'conditions' => array('User.id = Email.user_id')
               ),
          ),
          'conditions' => array(
               'OR' => array(
                   'Email.email LIKE' => $search,
                   'User.email LIKE' => $search,
                   'User.surname LIKE' => $search,
                   'User.former_surnames LIKE' => $search,
                )
          ),
          'order' => array('User.surname'),
     )
 );
```